# After Redirect to other page user stuck at one page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made two aspx pages: `photogallery.aspx` and `gallery.aspx`; `photogallery.aspx` contains a list of albums and `gallery.aspx` contains pictures related to the album selected by the user on the `photogallery.aspx` page. Also when user does not select any album at `photogallery.aspx` and try to access `gallery.aspx` they get redirected back to album (`photogallery.aspx`) but at this point user get stuck only between this two pages and when try to move other page (e.g `Home.aspx`) from navigation menu they can't move anywhere.

this is my code:

***Photogallery.aspx***

```
protected void testing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Data"] = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    Server.Transfer("Gallery.aspx");
}
```

***Gallery.aspx***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Data"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Photogallery.aspx/");
    }

    else
    {
        Bind();
    }
}
```

How to solve this stuck at one page problem???

Comment: You may need to provide more of the code in your page. Can you include the code you are using for your menu? Also, what do you mean when you say "user get stuck only between this two pages" and "they can't move anywhere"? Do they get redirected back to this page when they try to navigate to another page? Is any of this code being used as a base class or otherwise shared code between all of your pages?

Comment: What is the purpose of Server.Transfer? do you really need of it?

Comment: When the link button is clicked, why are you not navigating directly to gallery? Why are you going to photogallery?

Comment: Also, I would highly suggest reading through the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of this site. Try to include as much information/code as possible (while still being as concise as possible)  so that we can get a better idea of where you might be having a problem.

Comment: Can you show the code which is supposed to send the current page to `Home` page.

Comment: Photogallery is list of albums, contains separate own images. So link button gives me id of album, which user wants to open. Therefore I need to navigate to photogallery first instad of gallery.

Comment: When user not select any album first, and try to open gallery they redirect back to photogallery to first select album. But after redirecting back to photogallery, from this (photogallery ) page, when I try to navigate home. Aspx page I can't navigate  to home page. Also, browser link show me localhost://photogallery. Aspx/home. Aspx*. Instead of showing localhost://home. Aspx